# Natbib and tufte-book: is it possible to change the conjunction between authors?

Tags: natbib, apa-style, tufte

I can't find the way to change the conjunction **and** between authors in a `tufte-book` class with `natbib` and `apa` style.

[image: aksdjbvlaskj]

This is what we get but it should be as follows:

```
 Lagardera, F. eta Lavega, P (2003) ...
```

Any ideas??

Comment: What language is it?

Comment: `\renewcommand\betweenauthors{eta}`?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're working with the bibliography style `apa`, which dates back (according to the file's header information) to 1992. I suggest you proceed as follows:

- Find the file `apa.bst` in your TeX distribution. Make a copy of this file and call the copy (say) `apa-eta.bst`.
- Open the file `apa-eta.bst` in a text editor. The editor you use for your main tex files will do fine.
- In this file, there are two instances of the string `" and "`: the first in the function `format.names` (l. 250), and the second in the function  `format.lab.names` (l. 876). Change both strings to `" eta "`. (Observe the spaces before and after and/eta.)
- Save the file `apa-eta.bst` either in the directory that contains your main tex file or in a directory that's searched by BibTeX. If you choose the latter option, be sure to update the filename database of your TeX distribution in a suitable fashion.
- In your main tex file, change the argument of the `\bibliographystyle` instruction from `apa` to `apa-eta`.
- Rerun LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more to fully propagate all changes.

Happy BibTeXing!

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
@book{ll:2003,
  author    = "F. Lagardera and P. Lavega",
  title     = "Introducci{\'o}n a la praxiolog{\'i}a motriz",
  publisher = "Paidotribo",
  address   = "Barcelona",
  year      = 2003,
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[super]{tufte-book} % "super": for superscript-style citation call-outs
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{apa-eta}

\begin{document}
\cite{ll:2003}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Believe it or not, I cannot get the system to find the new file and use it... I could prepare the new .bst file following your precise instructions. Thanks for that. I keep trying...

Comment: @Raul-MdSG - Can you open a command window and type `kpsewhich apa.bst`?